# find dependencies in target/classes instead of local repository?

Tags: maven-2, compilation

Summary: I'm looking for a way to instruct maven to search for dependencies in target/classes instead of jar in the local repository

Say I have 2 modules, A and B where A depends on B. Both are listed in a module S. Normally I need to run 'mvn install' in S. I'm looking for a way to run 'mvn compile' so that when A is compiled its classpath will contain ../B/target/classes instead of ~/.m2/repository/com/company/b/1.0/b-1.0.jar.

(my reason is so that i can have continous compilation without the need to go through packaing and installation, or, more exactly, use 'mvn scala:cc' on multiple modules)

Comment: Has your issue been resolved in any way 9 years later in Maven 3.6.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible without horrible hacking, this is just not how maven works. Maven uses binary dependencies and needs a local repository to resolve them. So, the maven way to handle this is to launch a reactor build on all modules. Just in case, have a look at [Maven Tips and Tricks: Advanced Reactor Options](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/).

But, during development, can't you just import all your projects in your IDE and use "project references" (i.e. configure your projects to depend on source code instead of a JAR) like most Java developers are doing? This is the common approach to avoid having to `install` an artifact to "see" the modifications.

If this is not possible and if you really don't want to `install` artifacts into your local repository, then you'll have to move your code into a unique module.

Comment: "during development, can't you just import all your projects in your IDE" This unfortunately prohibits development in some important contexts, such as automation and command line environments. Doing `mvn install` is much slower in such cases, significantly crippling the iterative development process flow. Is there a rationale to this besides "this is just not how maven works"?

Answer (score 2):

i know this is annoying. which helped me here is definitely IDE support. eclipse and IntelliJ are clever to collect all dependencies once a maven-project import is done. even cross module dependencies are compiled live.